# Absolute positioning and window resize

Tags: html

There are two div tags absolutely positioned.
The point is to prevent the first one to go over the one on the right on window resize to less than total width.
p.s. : This only occurs in firefox.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My HTML File</title>
    <style>
        body{
            direction: rtl;
        }
        #sidebar{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 300px;
            min-height: 1000px;
            background-color: #66ccff;
        }
        #content{
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 300px;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            min-width: 1100px;
            background-color: #008844;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
<div id="content">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ....that's way we generally don't use absolute positioning for responsive layouts.

Comment: I agree with Diodeus, but either way, you should set up a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `left: 0;` from `#content`

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 300px;
    bottom: 0;
    /*left: 0;*/
    min-width: 1100px;
    background-color: #008844;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzjGn/8/)